# opening and saving image in python makes an empty file

Tags: python

I am just starting to learn python. I am trying to make a program that opens a file, crops it and saves it. I wrote this:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('boi.jpg')
crop = image.crop((0,0,200,200))
crop.save("boicropped.jpg","JPEG")
```

This makes an empty file that i can not open:
[image: boicropped]

i am sorry if it is an obvious mistake i am missing...

Comment: Does saving without cropping work? Any functions perhaps that report failure via returnvalues?

Comment: i tried image.save("boicropped.jpg","JPEG") and it allso makes an empty file. Allso i dont know what you mean by retunvalues

Comment: Do you know if the image was loaded correctly is yet another question that you should ask yourself.

Comment: Probably it was not loaded correctly, do you know how to find the cause of the error and fix it?

Comment: have you tried omitting the format param? so something like `crop.save(os.path.join(..., 'boicropped.jpg'))`? I had similar issues when setting format explicitly to `JPEG`

Comment: Probably is not helpful, find out whether it was loaded or not. Other than that, just run any example code or whatever you can find online that uses these functions. Run it in a debugger to observe it in operation, too!

Comment: I tried this: from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("boi.jpg")
im.rotate(45).show()
and it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the declaration of crop.  Encapsulate your cropping of image, and follow with .save.

Comment: if you mean like this "image.crop((0,0,200,200)).save('boicropped.jpg','JPEG')" it doesnt work

Comment: image = Image.open("boi.jpg")
crop = image.crop((0,0,200,200))
crop.save("boicropped.jpg")

I do not think extension is required, also double quotes may be needed to open that file.  This worked for me.